# Marriage Leave-Pay Deducted and How to ask for full pay?

Tags: salary, leave-of-absence, asia

I am working in a small company for a period of one year as a programmer in south east asia. Recently I took a 20 days leave for my marriage.After joining the company, this is my first leave that I applied.But When I come back, I got surprised to see that my pay has been deducted by half for the leave I taken.

They did some calculation according to my current leave balance. Here in Singapore they add your annual leave month by month.
I checked with my colleagues and they say that usually they will deduct month by month.

How can I discuss this with my boss in a right way so that I actually get the almost full pay.If I ask this, Do this have any consequences?

Comment: How much leave do you get?

Comment: This is not off topic.  It is not asking about what the policy is or how it should be.  The OP is asking how to address management about the issue

Answer (score 4):

Based upon what you've written, I'm assuming the following:

- The 20 days that you took exceeded your accrued annual leave balance at the time.
- The amount deducted from the pay is *only* to cover whatever overage existed between the amount of leave you took versus the amount of leave that you had accrued.

With that in mind, the best option would have been to sort this out *before* you took more leave than you had actually accrued.  Many companies will be accommodating of such requests (though results will vary by locale and industry), provided that you're not trying to take more leave than you'll accrue in a single year in advance.

Since it's too late for that, it sounds like your present options are:

1. Just accept the reduced pay if you're financially able to do so.  As long as they don't *also* deduct from your annual leave then it sounds like their accounting is correct.  In essence they're giving you 20 days of unpaid leave (since you had insufficient paid leave to cover the absence), and you will accrue an additional 20 days (or however many days you get per year) of *paid* leave this year.

   From a long-term standpoint there's no net difference between what they've done and what would happen had they set your annual leave balance to '-20 days' instead.  And on the positive side it means you can take your next vacation that much sooner.
2. Speak with your manager and/or HR, and see if they can update things to account for the absence as paid leave, and just deduct from your monthly leave accrual until the balance has been paid off.  I suspect they might be unwilling to do so, as from an accounting standpoint it's likely difficult/messy to update this sort of thing after the fact.

Option #1 is easy, since it basically requires doing nothing and has no negative consequences apart from the obvious short-term financial ones.

However, as long as you are polite about things, and apologetic for not discussing the issue *before* you took the time off, I doubt there'd be any negative consequences to pursuing option #2.

All you need to do is point out that you were under the impression that the balance would be taken from your future leave accrual and not deducted from your wages, and ask if they can switch to doing it that way.  Just be prepared for them to say 'no', and ready to drop the issue if they do.  If they say 'no' and you continue to press the issue, *then* you might run into negative consequences.

**Caveat Emptor**

I have no specific knowledge of social or workplace customs in Singapore.  It's possible (though in my view, unlikely) that asking for this sort of thing would violate some local taboo.  In which case there may be negative consequences.

If you feel that this is the sort of thing that's "just not talked about" where you are, then the safest option is not to talk about it.